# How do I merge two *.avi files into one

Tags: command-line, gui, video, ffmpeg

I have two `*.avi` files:

```
sequence1.avi
sequence2.avi
```

How do I merge these two files using a command-line or GUI?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a dedicated tool to do this, [`avimerge`](http://www.transcoding.org/transcode?Avimerge):

```
avimerge -o cd.avi -i cd1.avi cd2.avi
```

If not installed, install transcode: Avimerge is part of transcode package:
https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/transcode/avimerge.1.en.html
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/avimerge.1.html

Comment: Worth mentioning that transcode is no longer available for Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 13):

Easy with mencoder (shipped with mplayer in Arch Linux):

```
$ mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy video1.avi video2.avi -o final.avi
```

Comment: This has worked like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) can paste two videos together, at least if they have the same resolution and a few other constraints. Use “Append” from the “File” menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge avi files with `avimerge` from [Transcode](http://tcforge.berlios.de/) package:

```
avimerge -i file1.avi file2.avi -o output.avi
```

I know that it isn't GUI tool, but to have GUI you could use that script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file1=`kdialog --getopenfilename ~/ \*.avi`
file2=`kdialog --getopenfilename ~/ \*.avi`
output=`kdialog --getsavefilename ~/ \*.avi`
avimerge -i $file1 $file2 -o $output
```

It uses `kdialog` so it's for KDE users, GNOME users should modify it to use Zenity...

Comment: Your thirst for going ahead and give the Answer regardless should have been quenched by going here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/how-do-i-merge-two-avi-files-into-one. Also, see my Comment on the Accepted Answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry - somehow I missed that question...

Answer (score 1):

What about using [ffmpeg concat](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) like that:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i \
<(for f in $PWD/*.avi;do echo "file '$f'";done) \
-c copy output.avi
```

If you get an error **Unsafe file name** add `-safe 0` between `concat` and `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not wedded to the AVI container format as output, you can get easy lossless joining of AVI files from MKVtoolnix GUI. https://forums.plex.tv/t/howto-joining-multi-part-movies-files-with-mkvtoolnix-gui/113211 (The instructions in this link boil down to: add the first AVI file, right click > append > choose second file, then click "start muxing").

This also works for subtitles, mp4 files, etc. It also has the advantage of an output file that is more reliable to play and stream on modern players.