# How do I merge two *.srt files

Tags: command-line, video, video-subtitles

Please see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/how-do-i-merge-two-avi-files-into-one) question.

I have just merged two avi files `cd1.avi` and `cd1.avi` into `movie.avi` using:

```
avimerge -o movie.avi -i cd{1,2}.avi
```

Problem is that I had to *subtitle* files linked to the first `avi` files:

```
cd1.srt
cd2.srt
```

At first I tried simply to concatenate the files together:

```
cat cd{1,2}.srt > movie.srt
```

But that caused havoc with the subtitles... any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is pretty trivially done, since `.srt` files are just text files that contain time stamps -- all you need to do is add the length of `cd1.avi` to the times of all the subtitles in `cd2.srt`. You can find the length of `cd1.avi` with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i cd1.avi  # Look for the Duration: line
```

And then add that to `cd2.srt` using `srttool`

```
srttool -d 12345 -i cd2.srt  # 12345 is the amount to add in seconds
```

or:

```
srttool -a hh:mm:ss -i cd2.srt  # The first subtitle will now start at hh:mm:ss
```

Then you should just be able to concatenate the files together and renumber:

```
srttool -r -i cd.srt
```

---

I picked `srttool` because in Arch it comes with `transcode`, which you installed for [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/how-do-i-merge-two-avi-files-into-one); there are lots of other tools that can shift and merge `.srt` files too, and at least one website, [submerge](http://submerge.delarue-berlin.de/)

Comment: +1 thanks micheal, really appreciate your efforts with my questions

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. Only problem I found is that srttool puts output to the command line. I actually doesn't modify the file you want. A little redirection (>) and WHAMMO, it works perfectly. This has been a huge help and thank you very much.

Comment: How do you install srttool on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

I needed the subs from the second SRT file to be appended to the nearest EXISTING timing in the first SRT file, so came up with the script below.

For example, in this way you can join subtitles in different languages into a single file. You might also want to modify the script and append content from the other file with a different color. The only supported syntax for doing this in a SRT file is using something like `<font color="#00ffff">text here</font>`.

The script requires a recent python3 and the [`srt`](https://github.com/cdown/srt) module which can be installed with `pip3 install srt`.

#### Usage:

```
python3 merge_srt.py first.srt second.srt
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import sys
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

# pip3 install srt
import srt


def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x.start - pivot))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='merge SRT subtitles',
                                     usage="""
    Merge SRT subtitles:                                     
    \t{0} first.srt second.srt -o merged.srt
 """.format(Path(sys.argv[0]).name))

    parser.add_argument('srt1',
                        metavar='srt1',
                        help='SRT-file-1')
    parser.add_argument('srt2',
                        metavar='srt2',
                        help='SRT-file-2')
    parser.add_argument('--output-file', '-o',
                        default=None,
                        help='Output filename')
    parser.add_argument('--encoding', '-e',
                        default=None,
                        help='Input file encoding')
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

    srt1_path = Path(args.srt1)
    srt2_path = Path(args.srt2)

    with srt1_path.open(encoding=args.encoding or 'utf-8') as fi1:
        subs1 = {s.index: s for s in srt.parse(fi1)}

    with srt2_path.open(encoding=args.encoding or 'utf-8') as fi2:
        subs2 = {s.index: s for s in srt.parse(fi2)}

    # iterate all subs in srt2 and find the closest EXISTING slots in srt1
    for idx, sub in subs2.items():

        start: timedelta = sub.start
        sub_nearest_slot: srt.Subtitle = nearest(subs1.values(), start)
        sub_nearest_slot.content = f'{sub_nearest_slot.content}<br>{sub.content}'
        subs1[sub_nearest_slot.index] = sub_nearest_slot

    if not args.output_file:
        generated_srt = srt1_path.parent / (f'{srt1_path.stem}_MERGED_{srt1_path.suffix}')
    else:
        generated_srt = Path(args.output_file)

    with generated_srt.open(mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
        fout.write(srt.compose(list(subs1.values())))
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the accepted answer. Unfortunately, it depended on (a) an invocation of ffmpeg that exited with a non-zero exit code and (b) on srttool, which is not obviously available in homebrew.

Additionally, I was wanting something that would perform a bit more automation over several files (since I'm using a DJI drone and it splits files every 4GB).

I ended up writing [srt-concat](https://github.com/jaraco/jaraco.media#srt-concat) as part of the `jaraco.media` project. It does require a Python environment (and the expertise that requires), but it's readily installable and runnable. Just `pip install jaraco.media` into your Python environment, then run `python -m jaraco.media.srt-concat ...` according to the directions in that readme. It will attempt to detect the media file associated with each matching SRT file, calculate the durations of those files, and add the aggregated duration as it concatenates the SRT entries.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer uses `ffmpeg` and then `srttool`. If you already have `ffmpeg` installed, you can just use the [concat demuxer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/7381355) and don't need anything else:

```
$ cat mylist.txt
file '/path/to/file1.srt'
file '/path/to/file2.srt'
file '/path/to/file3.srt'
    
$ ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.srt
```