# How do I merge two *.avi files into one?

Tags: gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I merge two *.avi files into one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/how-do-i-merge-two-avi-files-into-one)

I have 2 `*.avi` files:

```
cd1.avi
cd2.avi
```

Which GUI allows me to merge these?